# Gindikin-Karpelevich formula in the quasi-split case

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups

In Euler Products (1971), Langlands established the Gindikin-Karpelevich formula for split reductive groups over the local fields $\mathbb{Q}_p$. On the other hand, the archimedean Gindikin-Karpelevich formula is for semisimple Lie groups which are quasi-split over $\mathbb{R}$.

Is there an analogue of the Gindikin-Karpelevich formula for quasi-split reductive groups over non-archimedean local fields?